# is there a good way to constructs objects with changing parameter types in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, parameter-passing

Im fairly new to c++ and wonder if there is a better solution to this problem. I currently have an abstract class with multiple diffrent classes (i_c) implementing that interface and constructors of other objects, who use these implemented classes as parameters one at a time. The other parameters stay the same for each constructor.
So my approach would be a constructor for each possible i_c for the object and a factory method, constructing the object depending on the parameter.
I know that you cant give the abstract class as a parameter, but is there another way to avoid writing a constructor for each parameter type?
Thanks in advance

The code itself is probably to long to post so ill try do it in an abstract form:

```cpp
class parent_robot
{
public:
    virtual void move_tcp() = 0;
};

class child_robot_a
    : public parent_robot
{
public:
    void move_tcp() override;
private:
    Eigen::Affine3d gripper_location_;
};

class child_robot_b
    : public parent_robot
{
public:
    void move_tcp() override;
private:
    Eigen::Affine3d camera_location_;
};

class child_robot_c
    : public parent_robot
{
public:
    void move_tcp() override;
private:
    Eigen::Affine3d gripper_location_;
};


class gui_object_identical_a{

gui_object_identical_a::gui_object_identical_a(
            child_robot_a& r_a, 
            identical_parameter_a& a, 
            identical_parameter_a& b)
            :
            child_robot_(r_a),
            member_a_(a),
            member_b_(b)
        {}
}

class gui_object_identical_b{

gui_object_identical_b::gui_object_identical_b(
            child_robot_b& r_b, 
            identical_parameter_a& a, 
            identical_parameter_a& b)
            :
            child_robot_(r_b),
            member_a_(a),
            member_b_(b)
        {}
}

class gui_object_identical_c{

gui_object_identical_c::gui_object_identical_c(
            child_robot_b& r_c, 
            identical_parameter_a& a, 
            identical_parameter_a& b)
            :
            child_robot_(r_c),
            member_a_(a),
            member_b_(b)
        {}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] written text is terrible for describing coding details.

Comment: If constructors differ in number or type of arguments, then you must write each and every constructor... unless you use templates.

Comment: Sounds like a job for templates, and for concepts (in the newest version of the C++ standard). You will find more information on that in your C++ textbook.

Comment: i added some example code. i hope it is useful

Comment: ill read into templates. thanks for the hint

Comment: Your `gui_object_identical_...` classes make copies of their `child_robot_...` parameters. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code making use of templates:

```
class parent_robot
{
public:
    virtual void move_tcp() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class child_robot
    : parent_robot
{
public:
    void move_tcp() override;
private:
    Eigen::Affine3d x_location_;
};

template<class T>
class gui_object_identical{

gui_object_identical_a::gui_object_identical(
            child_robot<T>& r_a, 
            identical_parameter_a& a, 
            identical_parameter_a& b)
            :
            child_robot_(r_a),
            member_a_(a),
            member_b_(b)
        {}
}
```

You could extend that to remove inheritance from `parent_robot` if you want, as the template class already ensures that all `child_robot` variants will have `move_tcp`. I renamed the location-member to `x_location_` as the type was the same for all three.

Comment: Your `child_robot` doesn't use the `T` parameter. Why is it needed?

Comment: Good point. It is not needed because OP's code snippet does also not have a difference between the three child robots (besides variable names). As the example is apparently incomplete, that also applies to my variation of it.

Comment: They all override `move_tcp`, presumably to do different things.

Comment: yeah sry, i didnt clarify that. the move_tcp func is diffrent for each object

Answer (score 0):

I should have searched better: You can use a pointer on the parent class in the argument list and input a pointer to the child:

```cpp
class gui_object_identical{

gui_object_identical::gui_object_identical(
            std::shared_ptr<parent_robot> r, 
            identical_parameter_a& a, 
            identical_parameter_a& b)
            :
            parent_robot_(r),
            member_a_(a),
            member_b_(b)
        {}
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<parent_robot> p = std::make_shared<child_robot_a>();
    auto gui = gui_object_identical(p);
}
```